# Message queues and triggered comms within a native app

Tags: c#, cloud-computing, message-queue, azure, native

I'm building a native app which currently has zero backend infrastructure.

With services like Firebase's Authentication, database and notifications means that all interactions are handled client-side within an Ionic app and consumed via Firebase javascript API.

I would like to start sending triggered emails and communications. Both manually triggered by other user interactions, and on regular intervals (daily/weekly summaries). I feel slightly nervous about depending solely on client-side to process these message, especially as this wouldn't scale nicely at all.

I'm familiar with writing API's and Services in .Net so I'd love to write something using the Azure message queue with something like Mandrill or Sendgrid. However it feels like there may be a far simpler solution. Perhaps Node.Js?

Open to ideas and suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using services like AWS SES,SNS and lambda (for logic)? I'm not familiar with the Azure equivalent services! Using those services would allow you to continue in your zero backend infrastructure.

Comment: Azure web app services allow you to do similar. What I'm looking for is a Message queue bus that interacts with FireBase and SendGrid. Both platforms have Node.js SDK's so I'll probably go with that option and deploy it straight to an Azure web app